# Endianness -- why do chars put in an Int16 print backwards?

Tags: c, xcode, char, endianness

The following C code, compiled and run in XCode:

```
UInt16 chars = 'ab';
printf("\nchars: %2.2s", (char*)&chars);
```

prints 'ba', rather than 'ab'.

Why?

Comment: Is `'ab'` allowed as a literal at all? Which compiler (platform) is that?

Comment: It's C. g++ (I think) running behind XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular implementation seems to store multi-character constants in little-endian format.  In the constant `'ab'` the character `'b'` is the least significant byte (the little end) and the character `'a'` is the most significant byte.  If you viewed `chars` as an array, it'd be `chars[0] = 'b'` and `chars[1] = 'a'`, and thus would be treated by printf as `"ba"`.

Also, I'm not sure how accurate you consider Wikipedia, but regarding [C syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Character_constants) it has this section:

> Multi-character constants (e.g. 'xy') are valid, although rarely
>   useful — they let one store several characters in an integer (e.g. 4
>   ASCII characters can fit in a 32-bit integer, 8 in a 64-bit one).
>   Since the order in which the characters are packed into one int is not
>   specified, portable use of multi-character constants is difficult.

So it appears the `'ab'` multi-character constant format should be avoided in general.

Answer (score 1):

Multicharacter character literals are implementation-defined:

> C99 6.4.4.4p10: "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined."

gcc and icl print `ba` on Windows 7. tcc prints `a` and drops the second letter altogether...

Comment: Implementation-defined values and undefined behavior are different things.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the system you're compiling/running your program on.

Obviously on your system, the short value is stored in memory as 0x6261 (ba): the little endian way.

When you ask to decode a string, printf will read byte by byte the value you have stored in memory, which actually is 'b', then 'a'. Thus your result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found in your tags: [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). On a little endian machine the least significant byte is stored first. This is a convention and does not affect efficiency at all.

Of course, this means that you cannot simply cast it to a character string, since the order of characters is wrong, because there are no significant bytes in a character string, but just a sequence.

If you want to view the bytes within your variable, I suggest using a debugger that can read the actual bytes.